# DeleteDuplicates[] does not work as expected on floating point values

Tags: list-manipulation, machine-precision

Here is my simple example, and in this case function `DeleteDuplicates` does not work as expected.

I want to `FindRoot` of my function $\chi[\nu]$, and since function $\chi$ is very sensitive to initial guess I decided to generate many initial conditions and 
leave only those solutions which are distinct. For this purpose I want to apply `DeleteDuplicates` on the resulting list of solution.

Here is the definition of my function:

```
χ[ν_] := 2*PolyGamma[1] - PolyGamma[1/2 + I*ν] - PolyGamma[1/2 - I*ν]
```

Here I generate many solution according to many random initial guesses

```
m = Table[v /. FindRoot[χ[v] == -1.2 - 0.2*I, {v, RandomComplex[]}], {i, 1, 10}]
```

And finally, I want to leave only distinct solutions:

```
DeleteDuplicates[m]
```

Unfortunately, the operation `DeleteDuplicates[m]` does not change the list `m`, although there are many identical values.

Namely:

```
DeleteDuplicates[m]
```

> ```
> {1.06423 + 0.0968739 I, 1.06423 + 0.0968739 I, 
>  1.06423 + 0.0968739 I, 1.06423 + 0.0968739 I, 0.0250407 + 1.00352 I, 
>  1.06423 + 0.0968739 I, 1.06423 + 0.0968739 I, 1.06423 + 0.0968739 I, 
>  0.0250407 + 1.00352 I, 1.06423 + 0.0968739 I}
> ```

I'm puzzled.

Any help or suggestions are very welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: Try something like `DeleteDuplicates[m, Abs[#1 - #2] < 0.01 &] `.

Comment: Thanks for editing Mr. Wizard! It looks much better :)

@b.gatessucks: Great, works like a charm. Could you explain the reason? I'm quite new to this.

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Andrew, please see the update to my answer for an important note about performance.

Comment: Andrew, what about changing "does not work properly" to "does not work as expected"? In fact it works properly, the cause is just seemingly identical numbers...

Comment: Related: [(19112)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19112/121)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would do well to understand the difference between tools that are intended for structural operations and those that are intended for mathematical operations.  [`DeleteDuplicates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html) is of the former, generally speaking.  As such it is comparing the exact [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) of the objects, or at least something close ([caveat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6166895/618728)).

As [b.gatessucks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/134/b-gatessucks) recommends in a comment you can use a mathematical comparison function for the equivalence test of `DeleteDuplicates`, e.g.:

```
 DeleteDuplicates[m, Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^-12 &]
```

> ```
> {1.06423 + 0.0968739 I, 0.0250407 + 1.00352 I}
> ```

Incidentally you could also use [`Union`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union.html), but the syntax is a bit different. Note the `( )`.

```
 Union[m, SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^-12 &)]
```

> ```
> {0.0250407 + 1.00352 I, 1.06423 + 0.0968739 I}
> ```

Using [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm.html) to show all of the digits of your expression you can see that they are not structurally identical in the (approximate) way that *Mathematica* "sees" them:

```
m // InputForm
```

> ```
> {1.0642275928442373 + 0.09687392021742822*I, 1.0642275928442366 + 0.09687392021742817*I, 
>  1.0642275928442366 + 0.09687392021742797*I, 1.064227592844237 + 0.09687392021742822*I, 
>  1.0642275928442373 + 0.09687392021742852*I, 1.0642275928442366 + 0.09687392021742793*I, 
>  1.0642275928442368 + 0.09687392021742801*I, 0.025040728196256346 + 1.0035162552538588*I, 
>  1.0642275928442377 + 0.0968739202174282*I, 1.0642275928442375 + 0.0968739202174283*I}
> ```

---

#### Performance

[Yves](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/131/yves-klett) reminded me to mention something about the performance of using a custom comparison function in `DeleteDuplicates` or `Union` as I did above.  For long lists this is always considerably slower than using the default method.  I gave an example with timings in [How to represent a list as a cycle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17042/121).

To apply that method here we could [`Round`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Round.html) the numbers beforehand:

```
Round[m, 10^-12] // DeleteDuplicates // N
```

> ```
> {1.06423 + 0.0968739 I, 0.0250407 + 1.00352 I}
> ```

I added `// N` to convert back to machine precision, but the values will not be precisely the same.  This probably doesn't matter if you consider numbers this close to be duplicates, but should you want the unchanged numbers you could use `GatherBy` and get performance not far distant.

```
First /@ GatherBy[m, Round[#, 10^-6] &]
```

Version 10.0 introduced [`DeleteDuplicatesBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicatesBy.html) which works similarly to the `GatherBy` method; it has the following syntax:

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[m, Round[#, 10^-6] &]
```

However it may not perform as well as `GatherBy`; see:

- [DeleteDuplicatesBy is not performing as I'd hoped. Am I missing something?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55294/121)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I see. It's like a comparison with epsilon of two floating point numbers. I assumed, that MATHEMATICA already does it for me.

Comment: Great, I missed InputForm. Without it it looks the same.

Comment: @Andrew On some mathematical operations it may, but as I stated `DeleteDuplicates` is generally a structural tool.  You will run into a similar problem in many cases.  For example, replacing elements in a list, because `Replace` and `ReplaceAll` are also structural tools:   `{0, 0., 0.00000} /. 0 -> 1`  -- you need a mathematical tool like `Equal`:  `{0, 0., 0.00000} /. x_ /; x == 0 -> 1`

Comment: @Andrew `FullForm` was a bit needlessly verbose here, but in general you should look at the `FullForm` when trying to understand how *Mathematica* will treat an expression using structural tools.  There are many cases where *not* using it will leave you quite befuddled as it can be *very* different from what is shown in standard output notation.

Comment: Perhaps a few words on possible performance caveats?

Comment: @Yves you mean the slow-down caused by using the second argument of `DeleteDuplicates`?  I didn't think it was appropriate unless we were comparing this to some other method that works.  But then, perhaps I should provide another method...

Comment: yes, I meant that. Sometimes it *may* be more effective to pre-process the list and then do a pure `DeleteDuplicates` - although your version is also what I´d go with in any case.

Comment: Admonish - lovely acoustics but far too harsh. I thought of it as "gently encouraging" at most...

Comment: @Yves Perhaps a harsher connotation than I intended; I was thinking ["**3.
to urge to a duty; remind**"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/admonish)

Comment: OH No please leave "admonished" in. It really is a lovely word (and I like the ambiguity)

Comment: How could this be done if instead of just one variable, FindRoot is solving for two or more variables? I.e., the output of FindRoot would be for example {{x-> 0.1,y-> 0.2, z->0.3}, {x-> 0.1,y-> 0.2, z->0.3}, ...}

Comment: @AJHC Converting to plain lists using `{x, y, z} /. solutions` seems like a good way to start.  For example with `m2 = {{x -> 0.1, y -> 0.2, z -> 0.3}, {x -> 0.1, y -> 0.2, z -> 0.3}, {x -> 0.17, y -> 0.22, z -> 0.314}}` then `DeleteDuplicates[{x, y, z} /. m2, AllTrue[Abs[# - #2], # < 10^-5 &] &]` or `DeleteDuplicatesBy[{x, y, z} /. m2, Round[#, 10^-5] &]` for the two fundamentally different methods described in my answer.  If you need to convert back to a list of rules then something like `Thread[{x, y, z} -> #] & /@ {{0.1, 0.2, 0.3}, {0.17, 0.22, 0.314}}`

Answer (score 1):

Note also that one can use `Equal[##] &` but not `Equal`:

```
DeleteDuplicates[m, Equal[##] &]
(*  {1.06423 + 0.0968739 I, 0.0250407 + 1.00352 I}  *)

DeleteDuplicates[m, Equal] // Length
(*  10  *)
```

This should work the same on most or all well-behaved `FindRoot` results.

As already noted, using something like `Equal[##] &` causes the performance to degrade, significantly on very long lists, but using `Equal` does not cause the same problem.  However, `Equal` does not tolerate difference, unlike `Equal[##] &`:

```
DeleteDuplicates[{1., 1. + $MachineEpsilon}, Equal]
    DeleteDuplicates[{1., 1. + 64 $MachineEpsilon}, Equal[##] &]
(*
  {1., 1.}
  {1.}
*)
```

Basically `DeleteDuplicates[.., Equal]` is the same as `DeleteDuplicates[]`.