# DeleteDuplicatesBy is not performing as I'd hoped. Am I missing something?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, memory, performance-tuning

Déjà vu: a new-in-v10 function should provide a better solution to an old problem, but my enthusiasm is curbed when I run timings.  This time the function is [`DeleteDuplicatesBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DeleteDuplicatesBy.html) and while its performance is miles ahead of [`PositionIndex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PositionIndex.html), I am still wondering if I am missing something or if this function was not ready for prime time.

In an effort to make this a question and short-circuit the cycle I shall summarize my question as:

1. What is the relative performance of `DeleteDuplicatesBy` and an obvious alternative?
2. Is there a case where the performance of this function clearly outstrips other methods?

Comment: It's *'amazing'* that this behavior can survive till now in v11.3. I think Wolfram **REALLY** needs to pause adding in fancy packages for a while and fix those numerous, and mostly silly, bugs accumulated in ages!...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

*The behavior described here is the same from 10.0.0 up to at least 10.3.*

**Summary**

We can look at the code of `DeleteDuplicatesBy` and it turns out it uses `GroupBy`. The test cases proposed by Mr.Wizard are all handled by some part of the code of `DeleteDuplicatesBy`. Other parts of this code also seem to have some issues. Most of the members of the `*By` family of functions seem to have side effects.

**How DeleteDuplicatesBy works**

It turns out `DeleteDuplicatesBy` is not a function written in C. So it's Mr.Wizard's pure-MMA skills vs that of a WRI programmer for this one ;).

Let's see what the definition of `DeleteDuplicatesBy` is. From v10.1.0 onwards, this may be done conveniently by using

```
<<GeneralUtilities`
PrintDefinitions@DeleteDuplicatesBy
```

If we predict where we will end up for a list, the definition basically says

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[expr_, f_] := Values[GroupBy[expr, f, First]]
```

I guess theoretically the best way to do this would have to involve some kind of hash table. I expect `GatherBy` also uses some kind of hash table, but who knows. It does not feel really surprising that an approach using a general purpose hash table like `Association` is slower than what is used by `GatherBy`. But if `Association` was exactly the right kind of hash table for this, I suppose this approach may have been really fast. Unfortunately, it seems `Association` is not the best choice for the job, but who knows if it is better for really large expressions (or something).

**Results of DeleteDuplicatesBy for "other expressions"**

By default we end up in the last branch in the `Which`, corresponding to `True`. It looks like this code may not give the results we might expect. Example

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[
 Hold[{a, 2}, {b, 1}, {c, 1}], Function[Null, Last@Unevaluated[#], HoldAll]]
```

> ```
> Hold[{a,2},{b,1},{c,1}]
> ```

This output is not expected, as we have

```
Function[Null, Last@Unevaluated[#], HoldAll][{b, 1}] == 
 Function[Null, Last@Unevaluated[#], HoldAll][{c, 1}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

As an aside, in the last argument of `Which`, the following snippet occurs

```
Table[{f[expr[[i]]], i}, {i, Length[expr]}]
```

This is kind of an anti pattern. Performance in cases like this is better when using `Map`, `Range` and `Transpose`. We can also see that the snippet does not work when `f` has a hold argument, as the code relies on `expr` to evaluate.

**Side effects of other `*By` family members**

This is actually what I previously (before edits) thought was going wrong in `DeleteDuplicatesBy`. This should not print.

```
a := Print["hello"]
SortBy[Hold[{a, 2}, {b, 2}, {c, 1}], 
 Function[Null, Last@Unevaluated[#], HoldAll]]
```

> ```
> "hello"
> Hold[{c,1},{a,2},{b,2}]
> ```

For the new `KeySortBy` we have

```
a := Print["hello"]
KeySortBy[Association@Unevaluated@{a -> 2, 3 -> 4}, Hold]
```

> ```
> "hello"
> <|3->4, a->2|>
> ```

Good old `SplitBy` has some side effects

```
SplitBy[Hold[{a, 1}, {b, 1}, {c, 2}], 
 Function[Null, Last@Unevaluated@#, HoldAll]]
```

> ```
> hello
> Hold[Hold[{a,1},{b,1}],Hold[{c,2}]]
> ```

`MaximalBy` (and I suppose `MinimalBy`), `GroupBy` and `CountsBy` do not have the bonus of working with `Unevaluated` without creating side effects

```
q := Print["arg"]
MaximalBy[Unevaluated@{Hold[a, 3], {q, 2}}, 
 Function[Null, Last@Unevaluated@#, HoldAll]]
```

> ```
> arg
> {Hold[a,3]}
> ```

But at least we can pretend they ignore `Unevaluated` rather that they give bad results. `CountDistinctBy` and of course `GatherBy` seem to works as expected.

Conclusion: `DeleteDuplicatesBy` may need a bit of work. I think some functions in the `*By` family could be a bit better, some more than others.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis.  I didn't try Spelunk on this function because I assumed that it would be implemented in C.  I'm pretty disappointed that this is how core functions are being handled in v10.

Comment: I note that for an association argument there are **four** conversions!: assoc -> list -> assoc -> list -> assoc

Comment: @Mr.Wizard note that for example `SplitBy` works in a similar way and already present in 7. `GatherBy` also has to deal with the problem that it has to rely on evaluation. It deals with this reasonably, as it generates a bunch of expressions which it then appears to compare in C. However, the one thing I don't like about `GatherBy` is that it only works on expressions with head `List`.

Comment: @Jacob It's funny but I knew `SplitBy` wasn't as fast as I'd have liked but I don't think I was aware it was merely a proxy for `Split[e, f[#1] === f[#2] &]`.  As I've said so often before: still so much to learn.  Please, so me the `SortBy` side effects you're referring to.

Comment: Hm... I think you're right, and that shouldn't leak.  Strange I never noticed it before.  I wonder if it's been the source for a few stray bugs I could never track down.  Good thing we have you around to find these things. :-)

Comment: I can't find `DeleteDuplicatesBy` documentation for anything other than lists and associations

Comment: Nice analysis +1

Comment: @Rojo hmm maybe I am spoiled, I have been using (regular) `DeleteDuplicates` with other heads a lot. Then maybe the critique should be that it doesn't work with `Unevaluated` and that it applies a rule without printing a message in a case where output is not sensible.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I agree. I don't really mind the messages, I take them as bonus warnings. Furthermore, it does work in the sense that it returns what it should (right?. e.g `GroupBy[Unevaluated@{Print@"a"; 2 + 2}, Hold, Hold]`), even though it leaks. But I hope they started taking the leaks more seriously and not evaluate stuff they don't need to. One sometimes needs to count on "sensible behaviour".

Comment: @Rojo I'm not sure, I don't like the output of this: `GroupBy[Unevaluated@{Print@"a";2+2,4,5},Hold]`, which is not the same as the output without `Unevaluated` and which is also not the same as what we would expect if we had assumed `Unevaluated` would work (three groups).

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom you are right, that output doesn't make sense to me either

Comment: @Rojo thanks, I've reported the leak in GroupBy already.

Comment: `SortBy` at least is documented to support any head.  Consider this work-around for the leak: `SortBy[Unevaluated /@ Hold[{a, 2}, {b, 2}, {c, 1}], {Last}][[All, 1]]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard that is an effective workaround, but I guess the stripping of `Unevaluated` in this case is kind of odd.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon thank you posting an answer and for reporting. I had not reported anything yet. If you feel I should report the other leaks (or if my answer can be improved), please let me know.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom go ahead and report the other leaks, but please ask that I be CC so I'm aware of what happens to them. And thanks for finding this, the behavior is doing multiple strange things with the evaluation semantics of GroupBy. P.S. To who do  you report such things and how?

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon you are welcome, I enjoy the interaction. About reporting, so far I have just mailed support@wolfram.com and I have always received nice replies. I am hoping send the bug report tomorrow, I want to make sure I don't complain about undocumented behaviour. I will make sure to ask them to CC you.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon  have reported this as "Re: [CASE:3460557] Evaluation leaks in functions that end in By". Sorry for the rather long delay.

Answer (score 22):

*Timing charts updated for version 10.0.2.  The behavior remains unchanged.*

---

Attempting to analyze the performance of this function in the manner that Taliesin Beynon did for `PositionIndex` I shall use the same tools.

The old method that will be compared in all cases below:

```
myDeDupeBy[x_, f_] := GatherBy[x, f][[All, 1]]
```

### Speed

A `BenchmarkPlot` of `DeleteDuplicatesBy` versus `myDeDupeBy`:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[
  {DeleteDuplicatesBy[#, Floor] &, myDeDupeBy[#, Floor] &},
  RandomReal[#, 2*#] &,
  2^Range[3, 22],
  "IncludeFits" -> True
]
```

[image]

Again my function starts off in the lead.  Let's try a higher duplicate density:

```
BenchmarkPlot[
  {DeleteDuplicatesBy[#, Floor] &, myDeDupeBy[#, Floor] &}, 
  RandomReal[#/4, 2*#] &,
  2^Range[3, 22],
  "IncludeFits" -> True
]
```

[image]

And a lower duplicate density:

```
BenchmarkPlot[
  {DeleteDuplicatesBy[#, Floor] &, myDeDupeBy[#, Floor] &}, 
  RandomReal[4*#, 2*#] &,
  2^Range[3, 22],
  "IncludeFits" -> True
]
```

[image]

`DeleteDuplicatesBy` seems to be a bit closer when there is high density so let's take that to the extreme with only two functionally unique values:

```
BenchmarkPlot[
  {DeleteDuplicatesBy[#, Floor] &, myDeDupeBy[#, Floor] &}, 
  RandomReal[2, 2*#] &,
  2^Range[3, 22],
  "IncludeFits" -> True
]
```

[image]

So it seems that my function is faster in nearly all cases, but when there is *extreme* duplication `DeleteDuplicatesBy` catches up.  That's not saying much for it.  Maybe its disappointing performance is an unavoidable trade-off of speed for memory?

### Memory

One might hope that a function that needs only retain one copy of each functional duplicate (`DeleteDuplicatesBy`) would have better memory performance that one that retains all elements (`GatherBy`).  Let's check:

```
(* in a fresh Kernel *)

a = RandomReal[1*^3, 1*^7];
DeleteDuplicatesBy[a, Floor];
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> 284876480
> ```

```
(* in a fresh Kernel *)

a = RandomReal[1*^3, 1*^7];
GatherBy[a, Floor];
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> 284870272
> ```

So much for that hope. `GatherBy` actually uses slightly *less* memory.

If there is a use-case for `DeleteDuplicatesBy` apart from Associations I am not seeing it. :-/

Comment: thanks for the analysis. You should avoid doing the 2^n inside the example constructor function and use PowerRange instead of Range when supplying Benchmark or BenchmarkPlot with the range of n to test. This is because the library of time complexities does not assume that you've already done the transformation n -> log n, so you get those weird exponential fits.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon Thanks for the instruction. :-)

Comment: Mr.W, (@TaliesinBeynon), it seems the plots in your answer no longer work in v10.1.0. It seems that the function `IndexBy` has been removed and that `BenchmarkPlot` still refers to this. It also doesn't work without the options `"IncludeFits" -> True`. I will see if any other BenchmarkPlot work.

Comment: A `BenchMarkPlot` in another answer still works, but I cannot get the ones in your answer to work for now.

Comment: Anyway your function is still faster.

Answer (score 14):

This function will be rewritten in C for 10.0.2 and should come down to average-case complexity of $O(n)$ from its current $O(n \log(n))$. Note that the version most users will be bothered to write (and the way we advertized this before in the docpage for `DeleteDuplicates`) is $O(n^2)$, so most users are probably already winning.

In the meantime, my advice is to use this despite the suboptimal performance, unless it makes your program unusably slow. Premature optimization and all that. The main thing is that we can all rely on it being here for the rest of time, it is one less idiom that requires ugly boilerplate code.

Comment: Thanks (as always) for responding.  Can you tell me if the memory usage will be addressed?  I realize that's not a bug, and it *may* be unavoidable, but it would be *great* if it used less memory.  By the way I'd like to chat again; when might you have time?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard memory usage will still have to be $O(n)$ in the worst case, when $n = n_{unique}$. Note the weird case in which the image is really large, you might then prefer the $O(n^2)$ time complexity of `DeleteDuplicates` because the space complexity will be $O(1)$.

Comment: Okay.  What about special handing of packed arrays to remove duplicates without unpacking?

Comment: It seems that the rewrite did not make it into 10.0.2.  Do you know if it is planned for 10.0.3?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was over-optimistic. This isn't planned for 10.0.3. Hopefully we'll do a bulk port at some point of a lot of these top-level implementations to C.