# Held keys in associations

Tags: bugs, evaluation, associations, hold

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.4**

*`Association` is new in 10.0.*

*Bug still present: `AssociationMap[Hold, p]`*

*Fixed bug: `Hold /@ p`*

---

Jacob Akkerboom [commented](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54853/why-is-the-new-positionindex-horribly-slow#comment157890_54853):

> Note that `PositionIndex` does work correctly with held expressions, whereas this is a bit painful to implement using `GatherBy`. `a = 1; PositionIndex[Unevaluated[{a, b, c, d}]]`

I finally got around to exploring this behavior and I am a bit confused and troubled by what I see.

First Jacob's example with a more explicit definition of `a`:

```
a = "Fail!";
p = PositionIndex[Unevaluated[{a, b, c, d}]]
```

> ```
> <|a -> {1}, b -> {2}, c -> {3}, d -> {4}|>
> ```

We see from this that `Association` is capable of containing unevaluated key names.  We can also extract the value corresponding to the key, or use the Association in a replacement:

```
p[Unevaluated @ a]

Hold[a, b, c] /. p
```

> ```
> {1}
>
> Hold[{1}, {2}, {3}]
> ```

Other operations prove problematic however.  In the first and third cases `a` evaluates undesirably:

```
Hold /@ p
KeyMap[Hold, p]
AssociationMap[Hold, p]
```

> ```
> <|"Fail!" -> Hold[{1}], b -> Hold[{2}], c -> Hold[{3}], d -> Hold[{4}]|>
>
> <|Hold[a] -> {1}, Hold[b] -> {2}, Hold[c] -> {3}, Hold[d] -> {4}|>
>
> Association[{Hold["Fail!" -> {1}], Hold[b -> {2}], Hold[c -> {3}], Hold[d -> {4}]}]
> ```

Since [`KeyMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/KeyMap.html) does work I thought we could use `HoldPattern` for the keys, but that too has problems in that the original lookups and replacements no longer work:

```
p2 = KeyMap[HoldPattern, p]
```

> ```
> <|HoldPattern[a] -> {1}, HoldPattern[b] -> {2}, HoldPattern[c] -> {3}, HoldPattern[d] -> {4}|>
> ```

```
p2[Unevaluated @ a]
Lookup[p2, Unevaluated[a]]
Hold[a, b, c] /. p2
```

> ```
> Missing["KeyAbsent", "Fail!"]
>
> Missing["KeyAbsent", Unevaluated[a]]
>
> Hold[a, b, c]
> ```

The lookup does work if we use an explicit `HoldPattern` but that seems somewhat undesirable:

```
p2[HoldPattern @ a]
```

> ```
> {1}
> ```

To make the replacement work we can convert the Association to a [`Dispatch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dispatch.html) expression:

```
Hold[a, b, c] /. Dispatch[p2]
```

> ```
> Hold[{1}, {2}, {3}]
> ```

My questions:

1. Is there a better way to work with unevaluated keys in an Association?
2. Is the illustrated behavior intended and desirable?
3. Are unevaluated keys an expected application of `Association`?  The behavior of `PositionIndex` indicates it may be but the conflicting results of the mapping operators seem unplanned.

Comment: Based on the second point in Tali's authoritative answer I have added but bugs tag.

Comment: I think my answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132331/4330) sheds some light on the situation after version 10.4.0. I believe the advice by WRI is "do not use unevaluated keys". The fact that you can create an `Association` with unevaluated keys using `PositionIndex` then puts us in a strange situation. I think maybe this should be considered a bug of `PositionIndex`. Maybe it does not make sense to expect anything from `AssociationMap` in this case, as this case is so unusual, so that maybe this should not be marked as a bug in `AssociationMap`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Wrap the entire key in `Hold`, if you really want to keep things that might evaluate in the keys of an association (`HoldPattern` is a red herring: keys aren't patterns). Alternatively use ToString. But generally this just sounds like a dangerous and confusing game to play, to me. What exactly are you trying to do? There is probably a better way that doesn't involve using the keys of associations.
2. No, `Map` and `AssociationMap` shouldn't evaluate keys. Please report that behavior to tech support and it'll wend its way to Konstantin. If it's a simple fix it'll probably happen for 10.0.2, if it requires a big rewrite or a loss in efficiency it may take longer.
3. Keys have to remain unevaluated for associations to have any efficiency advantages over ordinary lists of rules. There's no way around that.

Comment: Thanks, yet again, for replying.  Regarding: "What exactly are you trying to do?" my answer is: only trying to understand how this is supposed to work.  The fact that `PositionIndex` returned an association with unevaluated keys seemed at least unusual and worth exploring.

Comment: Would you please tell me if also *values* are to remain unevaluated?  I quoted you in answering [(89483)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89483/121) then realized I may be misrepresenting the facts.

Comment: To add to this answer, when you `Save` or `Compress` an `Association` and load it, it triggers evaluations of its keys. Theoretically this can be overcome with ``Internal`InheritedBlock``, but that is not safe and there are even [more problems](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98629/4330)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom that's worth reporting.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon In that case I will put it on my to do list, but I will probably report some other issues first, that can be communicated more easily. One reason is that I did not yet get a reply to my mail about [this issue](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55294/deleteduplicatesby-is-not-performing-as-id-hoped-am-i-missing-something#comment267597_55302) and I was not really happy about my presentation of the problems. I asked support to put you in the CC, as you requested. It also seems...

Comment: .. [your own report](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55294/deleteduplicatesby-is-not-performing-as-id-hoped-am-i-missing-something#comment159026_55302) did not cause any changes yet. For completeness, [another bug featuring GroupBy](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100139/4330) received a lot of attending on mma.se last week. Perhaps you could ping report about some of this, to see if things (especially your own report) did not get buried?

Comment: Just to be clear (so you don't think I'm lazy ;) ), I have just sent a report to support about another issue. Last time I sent 3 reports at once I did not get replies to two of them, so I figured this time I would sent one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

In 10.1.0 we have the new function `KeyValueMap`. You can use these functions, although they are not perfect

```
heldNormal[assoc_] := 
 Apply[Rule, Hold@Evaluate@KeyValueMap[Hold, assoc], {2}]
map[f_, assoc_] := 
 Association @@ 
  Unevaluated @@@ List@MapAt[f, heldNormal@assoc, {All, All, 2}]
associationMap[f_, assoc_] := 
 Association[ReleaseHold@Map[f, heldNormal[assoc], {2}]]
```

**Example**

With

```
testAssoc = Association[Unevaluated[{a -> b, c -> b}]];
b := (Print@#; #) &@"Fail";
a := (Print@#; #) &@"Boo";
```

We get

```
map[Hold, testAssoc]
associationMap[
 Function[Null, 
  Identity @@ RuleDelayed @@@ MapAt[Hold, Hold[#], {{1, 1}}], 
  HoldAll], testAssoc]
```

> ```
> <|a->Hold[b],c->Hold[b]|>
> <|Hold[a]:>b,Hold[c]:>b|>
> ```

**Notes**

Unfortunately `heldNormal` does not know whether to use `Rule` or `RuleDelayed`, which `Normal` does do. For this purpose, we could consider an alternative using something like the following snippet

```
Normal[Hold /@ KeyMap[Hold, testAssoc]]
```

Perhaps this answer can be extended with alternatives to other members of the `*By` family. See my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55302/4330).

Comment: I don't know why I did not see this until today.  A belated thanks and +1.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard you're welcome :)