# How does MapThread work with Associations?

Tags: associations

According to the documentation, `MapThread` works on `Association` objects. But it doesn't seem to evaluate the passed function. For example:

```
MapThread[#1 + #2 &, {<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>, <|a -> 5, b -> 6|>}]
```

returns:

> <|a -> (#1 + #2 &)[1, 5], b -> (#1 + #2 &)[2, 6]|>

I would have expected `<| a -> 6, b -> 8 |>`.

Comment: Evaluate /@ MapThread[Plus, ...] ?

Comment: It seems to work if the `Associations` are in separate `Lists`: `MapThread[#1 + #2 &, {{<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>}, {<|a -> 5, b -> 6|>}}]`

Comment: @RunnyKine I think that is merely accomplishing `<|a -> 1, b -> 2|> + <|a -> 5, b -> 6|>`. (Which itself is of interest however.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Indeed.

Comment: I vote for bug...

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer... some observations:

```
Activate/@MapThread[(#+#2)&, {<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>, <|a -> 5, b -> 6|>}]
Normal@MapThread[(#+#2)&,{<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>, <|a -> 5, b -> 6|>}]
ReleaseHold/@MapThread[(#+#2)&, {<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>, <|a -> 5, b -> 6|>}]
Evaluate/@MapThread[(#+#2)&, {<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>, <|a -> 5, b -> 6|>}]
MapThread[(#+#2)&,{<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>, <|a -> 5, b -> 6|>}, 0]
```

all give

```
<|a -> 6, b -> 8|>
```

and, as noted by Mr. Wizard, all are equivalent to,

<|a -> 1, b -> 2|> + <|a -> 5, b -> 6|>

Comment: +1 but realize that only `Map` is important here; e.g. `Evaluate` is incidental.

Comment: In your example using `Thread`, `Thread` is superfluous; you are merely adding the two associations which triggers automatic threading.  Likewise the use of `MapThread` with *levelspec* `0`.  See eldo's deleted answer and [my just-posed question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63293/121) on the subject.

Comment: @Mr.W got it ... finally ... thanks:)

Comment: One down, one to go. (grin) Now realize that `MapThread[(# + #2) &, {x, y}, 0]` is merely `x + y`.

Comment: Mr.W it is indeed...

Answer (score 4):

Evaluation with `Association` is at present poorly defined (IMO).  See: [Held keys in associations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59979/121).  Your example shows that `MapThread` *does* work on associations but the RHS fails to evaluate.  `Map` causes the elements to evaluate:

```
MapThread[# + #2 &, {<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>, <|a -> 5, b -> 6|>}]

Identity /@ %
```

> ```
> <|a -> (#1 + #2 &)[1, 5], b -> (#1 + #2 &)[2, 6]|>
>
> <|a -> 6, b -> 8|>
> ```

---

Since there appears to be confusion with regard to the function of some different proposals in other answers and comments I feel it needs to be pointed out that several of them work by simply evaluating:

```
<|a -> 1, b -> 2|> + <|a -> 5, b -> 6|>
```

Which somewhat surprisingly yields:

> ```
> <|a -> 6, b -> 8|>
> ```

As I cannot recall seeing this in the documentation I asked:

- [Listable functions thread over Associations; is this documented?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63293/121)

Answer (score 4):

It works with **V 13.3** (and maybe with some versions preceding it)

```
data = {<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>, <|a -> 5, b -> 6|>}

MapThread[#1 + #2 &, data]
```

<|a -> 6, b -> 8|>

```
MapThread[Plus, data]
```

<|a -> 6, b -> 8|>

But this fails without warnings:

```
MapThread[Total] @ data
```

<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>

Anyway, I think one should use `Merge`, which was specifically designed to work with `List`s of `Rule`s and `Association`s.

```
Merge[Total] @ data
```

<|a -> 6, b -> 8|>

```
Merge[Apply @ Plus] @ data
```

<|a -> 6, b -> 8|>

Comment: (+1)  Also `MapThread[Total[{##}]&, {<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>, <|a -> 5, b -> 6|>}]`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the resulting association from your code is unevaluated.

```
In=  MapThread[#1 + #2 &, {<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>, <|a -> 5, b -> 6|>}]
Out= <|a -> (#1 + #2 &)[1, 5], b -> (#1 + #2 &)[2, 6]|>
In=  %[a]
Out= 6
```

I think you can do it by

```
Merge[{<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>, <|a -> 5, b -> 6|>}, Total]
```