# How to make Association reflect new assignments

Tags: associations

How do I get `Association` to act like `List` in the following?

```
list = {a};
assoc = <|x -> a|>;
a = 1;
{list, assoc}
```

> ```
> {{1}, <|x -> a|>}
> ```

The `List` picks up the newly assigned value of `a`, but the `Association` does not. And why does `Association` behave like this?

Comment: You are mistaken. List does not pick up the new value. Just observe `??list` and you see that it still contains the initial `a`. The moment you evaluate `list`, it is replaced by its content, which is `{a}` and then Mathematica tries to further evaluate this by applying rules that are associated with `a`. Therefore, your question cannot simply be answered since your understanding of the behavior is not correct. What now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As halirutan notes the original value of `list` is retained; only its *evaluation* is changed by the new assignment `a = 1`.

Likewise the evaluation of the Association is also changed:

```
assoc = <|x -> a|>;
a = 1;
assoc[x]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

In *Mathematica* 10.0.2 `assoc` is also printed with the evaluated form of `a`:

```
assoc
```

> ```
> <|x -> 1|>
> ```

Its definition remains unchanged however:

```
?assoc
```

> ```
> Global`assoc
>
> assoc=<|x->a|>
> ```

To actually update the definition of `list` one could use `list = list` because the RHS fully evaluates.  However this is not the case with the `Association`.  You can force an evaluation of the values with a [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) operation:

```
assoc = Identity /@ assoc;

?assoc
```

> ```
> Global`assoc
>
> assoc=<|x->1|>
> ```

The behaviors illustrated may change as Association is further developed.  See for example:

- [Held keys in associations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59979/121)

Comment: I'm running Mathematica 10.0.2.0, and when I execute `assoc`, I get `<|x -> a|>`, not `<|x -> 1|>`.

Comment: @Fructose I am a Windows 7 user.  What about you?

Comment: OS X Yosemite 10.10.1.

Comment: One can also use Evaluate /@ assoc.