# Problem Using Evaluated Replace with Associations

Tags: list-manipulation, associations

If I define some function like:

```
toISOdate[data_List]:=DateString[data,{"Year","-","Month","-","Day"}]
```

and try to applicate it in an `Association`

```
ass = <|"date" -> {{2014, 1, 1}, {2014, 1, 2}}|>
```

as:

```
Replace[ass, a:{_, _, _} :> toISOdate[a], ∞]
```

I get, the non calculated form:

```
<|"date" -> {toISOdate[{2014, 1, 1}], toISOdate[{2014, 1, 2}]}|>
```

instead of

```
<|"date" -> {"2014-01-01", "2014-01-02"}|>
```

If I use `Normal` into `ass` as:

```
Replace[Normal@ass, (a : {_, _, _}) :> toISOdate[a], ∞]
```

I get the correct calculation, but lose the association form.

Is this a bug? How can I get it evaluated with `Association`?

Using Mathematica V10.1 on Mac

PS: I can't loose the association structure, the real case is more complex.

**Update:**

```
ass /. a : {_, _, _} :> toISOdate[a]
```

Works as expected.

Comment: If you assign the result of the `Replace` function to a variable, and recall it, it's correct (v 10.2 Mac OS X). `a = Replace[....]; a["date"]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm on Mac. I edited the question to add this information tks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taliesin Beynon stated in reply to [Held keys in associations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59979/121):

> Keys have to remain unevaluated for associations to have any efficiency advantages over ordinary lists of rules. There's no way around that.

Apparently this is simply another manifestation of [Replacement inside held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29317/121) and the same solution applies:

```
Replace[ass, a : {_, _, _} :> RuleCondition @ toISOdate[a], -2]
```

> ```
> <|"date" -> {"2014-01-01", "2014-01-02"}|>
> ```

The question then becomes why does `ReplaceAll` cause evaluation?  I think it should not, and I think *that* is a bug just as it is for `Map` and `AssociationMap`.

Comment: `RuleCondition` is undocumented no? +1

Comment: @Murta Yes indeed, but very convenient.  WReach introduced it to public use (at least within Stack Exchange) [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29319/121), I believe.

Comment: Very interesting to know.

Comment: @Murta I just realized a major problem with this answer: Taliesin said ***Keys*** have to remain unevaluated, not values.  Is this intended therefore?  I don't know.  I'll ask him.

Comment: so we should tag this post like a bug?

Comment: @Murta No, wait for clarification from Tali.  I *think* I still have the right interpretation, that he did not mean *only* keys but wrote keys because that's what my prior question was about, but I'll correct this answer if I am wrong.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard This feels like a bug to me... consider reporting it to Tech Support and I'll see what various other people in the company think.

Comment: @Tali Thanks!  But which part, `Replace`, or `ReplaceAll`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Replace

Comment: Is there any new information on whether this is really a bug & will be fixed? I'm still having the same issue in V11.0.1: <|"key" -> a + b|> /. {a -> 1, b -> 2} gives <|"key" -> 1 + 2|> and not <|"key" -> 3|>.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon do you care to reply to the comment immediately above?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't like this behavior and I've advocated against it within the company. Did you report it as a bug to Tech Support?