# ReplaceAll behavior change from 10.2 to 10.3

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, associations

Executing:

```
replace[res_] := res /. {a_Integer, b_Integer} :> (a + b);
l1 = <|"respID" -> {1,2} , "key2" -> <|"key2" -> {2, 1}|>|>;
l2 = {"respID" -> {1,2} , "key2" -> {"key2" -> {2, 1}}};

replace[l1]
replace[l2]
```

In version 10.2 I get:

> ```
> <|"respID" -> 3, "key2" -> <|"key2" -> 3|>|>
> {"respID" -> 3, "key2" -> {"key2" -> 3}}
> ```

And in version 10.3:

> ```
> <|"respID" -> 1 + 2, "key2" -> <|"key2" -> 2 + 1|>|>
> {"respID" -> 3, "key2" -> {"key2" -> 3}}
> ```

Is this a bug?
How can I force the evaluation as in 10.2, to prevent Hold[2+1] and get 3?

---

As a temporary solution I'm using a very clumsy function similar to this:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
replace2[res_] := Module[{temp  = res/.Association-> List},
    temp = temp /. {a_Integer, b_Integer} :> (a + b);
    ToAssociations@temp
]
replace2@l1
```

> ```
> <|"respID" -> 3, "key2" -> <|"key2" -> 3|>|>
> ```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Other workarounds would be forcing evaluation at replacement time using `RuleCondition[a + b]` as the RHS of the rule, or afterwards using eg `Map[Identity, replace[l1], -1]`

Comment: @SimonWoods, `RuleCondition` is undocumented? Insteresting, `replace[res_] := 
  res /. {a_Integer, b_Integer} :> RuleCondition[a + b];` works.

Comment: See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29319/862) for some more on `RuleCondition`

Comment: @SimonWoods tks, interesting function. I'll use it. IMHO worth while an answer.

Comment: In fact, given that `Association` serves as `HoldAllComplete` container (after the key-value pairs have been added, they are not re-evaluated), the new behavior seems more logical to me than the old one.

Comment: Related: [(89483)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89483/121) (your own question but linked for organizational purposes)

Comment: @Leonid That is what I said in my answer to the question I just linked above, however Tali commented there to the contrary, unless I misunderstand him.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Not sure. I think the behavior of `Replace` reported there is fine, and as it should be. I will talk to Tali about this when I get a chance.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by Leonid Shifrin in comments, the behaviour you observe is not specific to associations, but is true of any function with the attribute `HoldAll` (or `HoldAllComplete`, or the relevant `HoldFirst` or `HoldRest`).  As an example I use `Hold`.  The simple rule `{a_, b_}:>a+b` does not force evaluation.  To force it, you can use `With` in the right-hand side of the rule, and within it a condition: in order to find out whether the condition holds, *Mathematica* will have to evaluate the `With` construct, which injects the result in the right place.

```
Hold[{2, 3}] /. {a_Integer, b_Integer} :> a + b
Hold[{2, 3}] /. {a_Integer, b_Integer} :> With[{res = a + b}, res /; True]

(*gives
Hold[2 + 3]
Hold[5]
*)
```

Another option, as pointed out by Simon Woods, is to use `RuleCondition[a + b]` as the right-hand side, an undocumented function used under the hood to implement the `With` construction.