# DateString doesn't evaluate within Dataset

Tags: evaluation, dataset, associations, date-and-time

[11.1]

Starting with a `DateObject` in a `Dataset`:

```
data = Dataset[<|"a" -> Now|>]
```

and then applying `DateString`

```
d = data /. date_DateObject :> DateString[date]
```

we find that `d["a"]` evaluates to a `String`. However, `Normal[d]`gives `<|"a" -> DateString[DateObject[...]]|>`. So I have two questions:

1. Why doesn't `DateString[DateObject[...]]` evaluate to a `String` within the `Dataset` or the `Association`?
2. Is there a way to force it to evaluate *upon application of the `ReplaceAll`*, so that the value of `"a"` in the `Dataset` and the `Association` is a `String`?

Comment: Why not do something like `ds[All, DateString]`?

Comment: This is a property/problem of `Association` itself (rather than `Dataset`).  See [Problem Using Evaluated Replace with Associations](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89483/142).  As noted in that question, a work-around is `data /. date_DateObject :> RuleCondition@DateString[date]`.