# Bad performance from SubsetQ?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

Can I say this is a bad performance from the new V10 function `SubsetQ`?

Here are some tests comparing it to `Complement[l2, l1] === {}`

```
count1[data_,list_]:=Module[{r},
   r=SubsetQ[#,list]&/@data;
   Counts[r]
]

count2[data_,list_]:=Module[{r},
    r=Complement[list,#]==={}&/@data;
    Counts[r]
]
```

Small columns test:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
data = RandomInteger[100, {100000, 10}];
list = {4, 3, 2, 1};

count1[data, list] // AbsoluteTiming
count2[data, list] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.760775, <|False -> 99995, True -> 5|>}
>   {0.450933, <|False -> 99995,True -> 5|>}

Large columns test:

```
$HistoryLength=0;
data=RandomInteger[100,{100000,100}];
list={4, 3, 2, 1};

count1[data,list]//AbsoluteTiming
count2[data,list]//AbsoluteTiming
```

> {3.345720, <|False -> 97745, True -> 2255|>} {0.910420, <|False ->
>   97745, True -> 2255|>}

**Update:**

Still slow in V10.1

Comment: Filed as a possible speed issue. I believe it will get investigated.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Tks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SubsetQ` *is* implemented in top-level using `Complement[a, b] === {}`. It has some overhead because it has to treat associations specially, plus it has to go through the requisite error-handling rigmarole. But has the same time complexity in the length of the first argument:

[image]

But this is on the shortlist of functions to reimplement in C when we have time. There are other patients that are more worthy of the "Vitamin C" treatment, however :).

Comment: Tks for the explanation. An Hashed Operator form for `SubsetQ` (`IntersectingQ` and so on) would be really welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

After comments from RunnyKine...

Just another approach and timing:

```
subs[u_, v_] := Length@Intersection[u, v] == Length@v
```

Performance:

```
 BenchmarkPlot[{count1[#, list] &, count2[#, list] &, 
 Tally@Map[Function[x, subs[x, list]], #] &}, 
 RandomInteger[100, {100000, #}] &, PowerRange[1, 1000], 
 "IncludeFits" -> True, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: See [the comment below Mr. Wizard's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55294/deleteduplicatesby-is-not-performing-as-id-hoped-am-i-missing-something?lq=1) in relation to the weird exponential fits in your timings.

Comment: @RunnyKine thank you! see edit...still something problematic with `count1`