# Compare some lists, if elements are almost equal

Tags: list-manipulation

I've got the solutions of three systems on two variables (a and b) that gives results sometimes almost equal. The three list are not of equal length!
For example:

```
sol1={{1.13627*10^-10, 0.517141}, {1822.1623, 0.130514}, {4104.7111, 
0.303997}, {3.89363*10^19, 1.01968}};
sol2={{5.56174*10^-10, 0.517141}, {1822.1612, 0.130514}, {3592.4222, 0.26549}};
sol3={{1.75707*10^-11, 0.517141}, {1822.1723, 0.130514}, {3273.7822, 
0.228122}, {806077., 2.98304}}
```

As you can notice the second term of sol1, the second term of sol2, and the second term of sol3 are almost equal. I want to extract only one of them, for example {1822.1623, 0.130514}.
So, can I extract the couple of solutions that are almost equal? For example if |ai-aj|<0.01 and |bi-bj|<0.0001?
Thanks!

Comment: Related, perhaps duplicate: [(21711)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21711).  If possible `Round` (quantize) your values rather than using `SameTest`; see my answer there for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Intersection` or `Union` with the option `SameTest`. For example, solutions for all 3 equations:

```
Intersection[sol1, sol2, sol3, 
  SameTest -> (Abs[#[[1]] - #2[[1]]] < 0.01 && Abs[#[[2]] - #2[[2]]] < 0.0001 &)]

(* {{1.13627*10^-10, 0.517141}, {1822.16, 0.130514}} *)
```

Or if you want to gather almost equal solutions:

```
Gather[Join[sol1, sol2, sol3], 
 Abs[#[[1]] - #2[[1]]] < 0.01 && Abs[#[[2]] - #2[[2]]] < 0.0001 &]

(* {{{1.13627*10^-10, 0.517141}, {5.56174*10^-10, 0.517141}, {1.75707*10^-11, 0.517141}}, 
    {{1822.16, 0.130514}, {1822.16, 0.130514}, {1822.17, 0.130514}},
    {{4104.71, 0.303997}}, 
    {{3.89363*10^19, 1.01968}}, 
    {{3592.42, 0.26549}}, 
    {{3273.78, 0.228122}}, 
    {{806077., 2.98304}}} *)
```

Or to find all solutions, which are close to `sol1[[2]]`

```
With[{s = sol1[[2]]},
 Select[Join[sol1, sol2, sol3], 
  Abs[#[[1]] - s[[1]]] < 0.01 && Abs[#[[2]] - s[[2]]] < 0.0001 &]]
(* {{1822.16, 0.130514}, {1822.16, 0.130514}, {1822.17, 0.130514}} *)
```

I hope one of these cases helps you.

Comment: In fact I used it, but it gives two elements. I want only one element in the list.
Thank you anyway

Comment: @meriens What do you mean? Find solutions that are close to `{1822.1623, 0.130514}` if it exist?

Comment: y problem is that I do not consider solution too small. I solve myself this problem, and now I can use correctly your solution. Thanks again.