# Checking for duplicates in sublists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list with contains entries that are length 8 sublists,i.e.

`L1={{a1,b1,c1,d1,A1,B1,C1,D1},{a2,b2,c2,d2,A2,B2,C2,D2},...}` and so on.

Now, in my problem two sublists are identical if the product of the first 4 entries of two sublists is identical. In this case I want to throw one of them out. My try at this was as follows:

```
Do[If[Product[L1[[i]][[k]], {k, 1, 4}] == Product[L1[[j]][[m]], {m, 1, 4}],
    Delete[L1,j], {i, 1, Length[L1]}, {j, i + 1, Length[L1]}];
```

but this doesn't work because in this way I'm changing `L1` while I'm working with it. How can I improve my code / make it right? I don't see it right now...Thanks!

Comment: check out `DeleteDuplicates`, using the 2nd argument (`test`). There is a nice example you might want to apply/adapt in the `Scope` section in the documentation center.

Comment: Also, I'm guessing that your example does not work because `Delete[L1,j]` does not do anything. Notice that `L1=Delete[L1,j]` is not a fix, you will get lost with indices. Maybe try `L1[[j]]=""` and at the end `L1=L1/.""->Sequence[]`. Just for sport because you should use something built in, like `DeleteDuplicates`/

Comment: Please add a concrete working `L1` (and the wanted result) for ease of testing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are a lot of questions on this site already about deleting duplicates and filtering lists.  You'll probably learn a lot if you take the time to search for and read some of them.  From several you could learn that the second argument of `DeleteDuplicates` is rarely a highly efficient way to approach a problem such as this and it is far better to use `GatherBy` where possible.

Compare the performance:

```
ss = Subsets[Range@16, {8}];

DeleteDuplicates[ss, Times @@ Take[#1, 4] == Times @@ Take[#2, 4] &] // Timing // First

First /@ GatherBy[ss, Times @@ Take[#, 4] &] // Timing // First
```

> 1.919
>
> 0.

The second method is so fast we must run it multiple times slow it down:

```
Do[First /@ GatherBy[ss, Times @@ Take[#, 4] &], {400}] // Timing // First
```

> 1.919

So we see that `GatherBy` is about 400 times faster on this size of problem.  On larger sets it will be comparatively even faster as it has superior computational complexity.

---

For fun, as an additional optimization we can compute the product in a vectorized form (with tuning thanks to [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2)) and extract our indices using Szabolcs's fine method from the second link below.  This is roughly 850 times faster than `DeleteDuplicates`:

```
Do[
  With[{prod = Times @@ Take[ss\[Transpose], 4]},
    ss[[GatherBy[Range@Length@prod, prod[[#]] &][[All, 1]]]]
  ],
  {850}
] // Timing // First
```

> 1.903

---

Related examples:

[How to represent a list as a cycle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17041/121)
[How to efficiently find positions of duplicates?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21341/121)
[DeleteDuplicates[] does not work as expected on floating point values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21711/121)
[Sort+Union on a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27274/121)
[Intersection for lists of numeric data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28695/121)

Comment: In Szabolcs' method, substituting `prod = Times @@ (Take[ss\[Transpose], 4])`, I get 1000 times faster. Would you confirm, please?

Comment: @MichaelE2 That would be one heck of an improvement.  Let me check!

Comment: I hope it's clear I meant 1000 times faster than `DeleteDuplicates`. :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 heheh, ah, that sounds more likely.  It's surely a better way to write that operation; I don't know what I was thinking (or rather wasn't).

Comment: @MichaelE2 I only got 850-900 times faster here but still nice.  Thanks!

Comment: is there a place that describes the underlying algorithm used in functions such as `GatherBy` and `DeleteDuplicates`?

Comment: @Jonie Not that I am aware of but I bet that would make a nice Question; you could include `Union` and `Gather` (with non-default methods) as well.  Do you care to ask that?

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer. Didn't know about GatherBy :)

Answer (score 9):

How about:

```
DeleteDuplicates[list, Times @@ Take[#1, 4] == Times @@ Take[#2, 4] &]
```

Answer (score 8):

If your `L1` is long (length `n`) it may be reasonable to calculate each `Product` once rather than `n-1` times like `DeleteDuplicates` does.

Let's calculate those products and then we can compare only the results.

```
l2 = {Times @@ #[[ ;; 4]], #} & /@ list; 
DeleteDuplicates[l2, #1[[ 1]] == #2[[ 1]] &][[;; , 2]]
```

We can see, it does matter:

```
n = 10^3;
L1 = RandomInteger[{1, 4}, {n, 7}];

DeleteDuplicates[L1, 
                 Times @@ Take[#1, 4] == Times @@ Take[#2, 4] &
                ] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.203125
> ```

```
DeleteDuplicates[{Times @@ #[[ ;; 4]], #} & /@ L1 ,
                 #1[[ 1]] == #2[[ 1]] &
                ][[ ;; , 2]] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.078125
> ```

Comment: +1. Precomputing the products is a nice trick, especially in cases where the complexity is greater than linear, as you point out.  Even if `DeleteDuplicates` gets thrashed by `GatherBy`. ;)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you. Do you know any source about why `DeleteDuplicates` is so slow? I can't recall any reason why it has to. Also this trick should have been done by `DD` itself :)

Comment: According to this [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19112/how-can-i-remove-matching-sublists-from-my-list/19118#19118) (Leonid Shifrin), `DeleteDuplicates` is quadratic with an explicit comparison function.  See also [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/QcTO_fULJZg).  I would think that it has to use a general purpose algorithm that does not assume the comparison is symmetric or transitive.  The actual complexity depends on the number of duplicates, too.

Answer (score 1):

`DeleteDuplicatesBy` (versions 10+) is almost as fast as `GatherBy`:

```
ss = Subsets[Range@16, {8}];

DeleteDuplicatesBy[Times @@ Take[#, 4] &][ss]// RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0058

```
First /@ GatherBy[ss, Times @@ Take[#, 4] &] // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0053

```
DeleteDuplicates[ss, Times @@ Take[#1, 4] == Times @@ Take[#2, 4] &] //
  RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 2.83