# In a list of points, how to efficiently delete points which are close to other points?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

Consider a list of points:

```
pts = Partition[RandomReal[1, 10000], 2];
ListPlot[pts]
```

[image]

I'd like to delete points so that the minimum distance between two points is 0.05. The following code does the job:

```
pts2 = {pts[[1]]};
Table[If[Min[Map[Norm[pts[[i]] - #] &, pts2]] > 0.05, 
AppendTo[pts2, pts[[i]]]], {i, 2, Length[pts], 
1}]; // AbsoluteTiming (* -> 1.35 *)
ListPlot[pts2]
```

[image]

But it becomes slow for large lists, probably because of `AppendTo` which does not know what type is going to come next.

How could this be done more efficiently? Note: there is no uniqueness of the resulting list, but that's not a problem.

*Just for better referencing, let me give another formulation of the question: How to delete points in a neighbourhood of other points of a list?*

Comment: try using `Nearest`

Comment: `pts2 = Union[pts, SameTest -> (Norm[#1 - #2] < 0.05 &)];`

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(32409)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32409/121)  Related: [(2594)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2594/121)

Comment: Just for you to keep in mind: `Union` with `SameTest` option set explicitly, has quadratic complexity in the number of points, because it performs pairwise conparisons.

Comment: Is there a reason you're generating then deleting, vs just properly generating in the first place? There are algorithms for blue noise that will easily generate millions of points / sec with the conditions of OP...

Comment: @ciao Yes, there is: here the points are random, for the MWE, but in practice I start with a given `pts`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I believe that.  But what happens here `i = 0;
f[x_, y_] := (i++; Norm[x - y] < 0.05);
pts2 = Union[RandomReal[1, 10000], SameTest -> f];
i` ?

Comment: @belisarius I have no idea. But it can't be right. Without a deep analysis (which is very unlikely to be happening inside `Union`), it is impossible to optimize and move away from pairwise comparisons. In fact, the norm-based sameness function is not even transitive. So, even though the result looks right, I suspect that `Union` is doing something wrong here. Unless, of course, it can analyze the sameness function way deeper than I can imagine.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I will try to do a few experiments when I get enough spare time. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following is a much faster, but not optimal, recursive solution:

```
pts = RandomReal[1, {10000, 2}];
f = Nearest[pts];

k[{}, r_] := r
k[ptsaux_, r_: {}] := Module[{x = RandomChoice[ptsaux]}, 
                      k[Complement[ptsaux, f[x, {Infinity, .05}]],  Append[r, x]]]

ListPlot@k[pts]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Some timings show this is two orders of magnitude faster than the OP's method:

```
ops[pts_] := Module[{pts2},
  pts2 = {pts[[1]]};
  Table[If[Min[Map[Norm[pts[[i]] - #] &, pts2]] > 0.05, 
    AppendTo[pts2, pts[[i]]]], {i, 2, Length[pts], 1}];
  pts2]

bobs[pts_] := Union[pts, SameTest -> (Norm[#1 - #2] < 0.05 &)]

belis[pts_] := Module[{f, k},
  f = Nearest[pts];
  k[{}, r_] := r;
  k[ptsaux_, r_: {}] := Module[{x = RandomChoice[ptsaux]}, 
                        k[Complement[ptsaux, f[x, {Infinity, .05}]], Append[r, x]]];
  k[pts]]


lens = {1000, 3000, 5000, 10000};
pts = RandomReal[1, {#, 2}] & /@ lens;
ls = First /@ {Timing[ops@#;], Timing[bobs@#;], Timing[belis@#;]} & /@  pts;
ListLogLinePlot[  MapThread[List, {ConstantArray[lens, 3], Transpose@ls}, 2], 
               PlotLegends -> {"OP", "BOB", "BELI"}, Joined ->True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @belisarius And therein lies one of my biggest gripes... the "I really need this, but I'm accepting something else..." switcheroo that happens here way too often. So now, a user searches for "fast...", gets this question  as a hit, and is led to the slowest solution. DOH! +1 on you, shame on that kind of nonsense.

Comment: @belisarius Your code'efficiency impressed me a lot.But if the element is a Disk with diffrence radius instead of Point.Can you do same thing efficiencly?I'm confusion with this problem in long time,Could you help me to try it?

Comment: @belisarius - Amazing. How do you think of these things? One question I have is I thought that `Append` was to be avoided., How is it that you are able to get away with this? Second question, I tried `Trace` but it pretty much upchucked. How can I figure out how many steps are used in the recursion?

Comment: @march Thank you, that works.

Comment: @JackLaVigne Knowing that `Nearest[ ]` is the most efficient Mathematica function for ranking distances helps to think these things :). WRT your concerns about `Append[ ]`, you are right but .... I'm appending only a few points. Most of the points get discarded. If you want to improve this little program try to optimize the `DeleteCases[ ]`instead of the `Append[ ]` part :)

Comment: Any idea why we don't observe the quadratic complexity indicated by @LeonidShifrin?

Comment: @anderstood and belisarius: I got a moderator notice of many comments.  Could you condense these and include anything of lasting import in the answer?

Comment: No need to be sorry. :-)  I think the notice serves a useful purpose however as sometimes one does not realize how long the comments have grown.

Comment: I'm back with your solution and it's still really nice. Why do you use `RandomChoice` rather than the first element, for example? Also, you can gain a few characters using `All` instead of `Infinity` :).

Comment: @belisarius   the instruction you used in timings compare ListLogLinePlot which version of Mathematica is? it is not working on 11.1  neither it appears in help files

Answer (score 15):

```
pts = Partition[RandomReal[1, 10000], 2];

ListPlot[pts]
```

[image]

Use `SameTest` option with `Union`

```
pts2 = Union[pts, SameTest -> (Norm[#1 - #2] < 0.05 &)];

Length[pts2]

326

ListPlot[pts2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The following "solution" has the benefits of:

- making a very a *uniform* grid.
- being fast.

It has the (perhaps mortal) drawbacks of:

- not being automated.
- being pretty liberal about kicking out points.

Nonetheless, I wanted to play a little. Here's my take: generate a square grid of points and use `Nearest` to pick out the points nearest to the gridpoints:

```
pts = Partition[RandomReal[1, 10000], 2];
nearestOnGrid[points_, d_] := Nearest[points, Outer[List, Range[0, 1, d], Range[0, 1, d]]~Flatten~1]~Flatten~1
testDistances[grid_, leastD_] := Min[EuclideanDistance @@@ grid~Subsets~{2}] < leastD
```

Then, if we do

```
grid = nearestOnGrid[pts, 0.074]; // AbsoluteTiming
testDistances[grid, 0.05] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.000957, Null} *)
(* {0.016401, True} *)
```

Note that the choice of `0.074` was not automated. I used `testDistances` to find a value for the grid-spacing that made it `True`. However, since this takes `0.016` seconds, trying to automate the procedure with some sort of bracketing method will definitely make this slower than the rest of the options above.

Nonetheless, the results are:

```
GraphicsRow[{ListPlot[pts], ListPlot[grid]}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: Your grid would look a bit uniformer if you applied aspect ratio of 1

Answer (score 4):

one more.. this I think fares well for very large n.

```
result = NestWhile[ 
            Nest[ Complement[#, Rest@Nearest[ # , RandomChoice[#] ,
              { Infinity, .05}]] & , #, Ceiling[(Length@#)/100] ] &, pts,
                  Min[EuclideanDistance @@@ Nearest[#, #, 2]] < .05 & ];
```

Kind of ugly to double `Nest` but the convergence test is the expensive part..

Comment: No need to do such an expensive test - I cobbled up a similar idea (did not bother posting since OP accepted a slow answer) - just nest ~Sqrt[numpts], then do a pass over remaining points. 3-4X faster than *belisarius*'s neat answer. +1, o/c...

Comment: @ciao Might be of interest for other users though...

Comment: Doesn't run here :( ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/k7otu.png) - Have you copied faithfully?

Comment: @belisarius: New form for `Nearest`... does not work on earlier V of MMA (not sure when added, but it's the `Nearest[{...},{...}]` form, equivalent (but I'd imagine faster than) `Nearest[{...},#]&/@{...}`

Comment: @ciao Thanks! They will keep overloading those functions syntax until one doesn't know what the heck a program is doing  anymore :)

Comment: @ciao `3-4X faster than belisarius's neat answer`? But as my try, it is even slower than my [this answer..](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162120/21532)

Answer (score 1):

Another style of coding by `NestWhile` instead of recursion in current accepted answer.

```
pts = RandomReal[1, {10000, 2}];
f = Nearest[pts];

pts = Last[NestWhile[Apply[{Complement[#, f[x = RandomChoice[#], {All, .05}]], 
       Append[#2, x]} &], {pts, {}}, Length@First[#] != 0 &]];
ListPlot[pts]
```

[image]