# In a list of Disk, how to efficiently delete Disk which are close to other Disk?

Tags: list-manipulation, image-processing, image

I want to draw pictrue like this:

[image]

My code is:

```
mycountry=BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@CountryData["China","Polygon"];



    list={Disk[RandomPoint[mycountry],RandomReal[0.01]]};
        While[Length[list]<50,disk=Disk[center=
RandomPoint[mycountry],r=RandomReal[{1,5}]];If[And@@((EuclideanDistance[center,
#[[1]]]>r+#[[2]])&/@list),
    AppendTo[list,disk]]]//AbsoluteTiming

(*{19.357, Null}*)



    Graphics[Transpose[{RandomColor[Hue[1/3,
NormalDistribution[.6,.2],NormalDistribution[.6,.07]],list//Length],Disk@@@list}]]
```

[image]

As you see,The way ahead of me is long,the `Length[list]` is just `50`,but the time is `19s`.Then I use the @belisarius 's `SameTest` in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95384/in-a-list-of-points-how-to-efficiently-delete-points-which-are-close-to-other-p),Then the `While` can be:

```
        list={Disk[RandomPoint[mycountry],RandomReal[0.01]]};
        BlockRandom@While[Length[list]<50,disk=Disk[RandomPoint[mycountry],
RandomReal[{1,5}]];list=Union[Append[list,disk],SameTest->(EuclideanDistance[#1[[1]],#2[[1]]]<(#1[[2]]+#2[[2]])&)]]//AbsoluteTiming

(*{44.0782, Null}*)
```

Although I have tried `SameTest->(EuclideanDistance[#1[[1]],#2[[1]]]<(#1[[2]]+#2[[2]])&)`,`SameTest -> (! Region`AlmostDisjointQ[{#1, #2}] &)`and`SameTest->(!Region`RegionDisjoint[#1,#2]&)`,The speed is slow still.By the way,I found a bug in a undocument function of Region`RegionSubset,such as

```
    If[Region`RegionSubset[disk,mycountry]&&And@@((EuclideanDistance[center,
#[[1]]]>r+#[[2]])&/@list),AppendTo[list,disk]]
```

The Region`RegionSubset don't work.So anybody can try a faster version to me?

ps:(and how can I input "`" normally in stackexchange?)

Comment: If you want the disks packed densely, consult:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87676/random-non-overlapping-disks-in-a-square/87694#87694

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  Thanks for your prompt.And the post's typesets is disorder,Can you tell me how to type a context symbol?I should be refind the typesets.

Comment: @yode I showed you how to do it, and then you changed it back. But you can still see how to do it in the question's history.

Comment: Is there a difference between this question and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40334/731) question?

Comment: @Pickett I'm sorry to hear that.Or you can change it again.¯ㅂ¯,The networ acess to SE is too slow in my country.

Comment: Also related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47683/5