# How to generate approximately equally spaced points efficiently

Tags: performance-tuning, finite-element-method, regions, geometry, computational-geometry

I don't very content with current method.So a better solution is expected still.I hope it meet two conditions in following.

1. That space is approximately equivalence.
2. We can control how many points to produce.

---

*v11.1* provides a new function [`SpherePoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SpherePoints.html). As the *Details*

> `SpherePoints[n]` gives exactly equally spaced points in certain cases for small `n`. In other cases, it places points so they are **approximately equally spaced**.

Can we achieve the same goal i.e. approximately equally spaced points in an **arbitrary 2D Region**?

The following is my attempt based on `Union`:

```
SeedRandom[1]
region = ConvexHullMesh[RandomReal[1, {100, 2}]];
UniformPts = 
  Union[RandomPoint[region, 50000], 
   SameTest -> (EuclideanDistance[#1, #2] < .1 &)];
Show[region, Graphics[Point[UniformPts]]]
```

[image]

Nevertheless, this approach has two weakness:

1. It is slow with a large number of pre-generated points i.e. the 2nd argument of `RandomPoint`, while the space won't be uniform enough if I don't pre-generate enough points, here's an example:

   [image]
2. The number of resulting points isn't controllable.

Comment: Is the region always 2D?

Comment: @Kagaratsch Yes..

Comment: See the edit of my answer.

Comment: Related: [How to get a specified number of points that are nearly equally spaced in a closed rectangle](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136447/how-to-get-a-specified-number-of-points-that-are-nearly-equally-spaced-in-a-clos/136450)

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95384/in-a-list-of-points-how-to-efficiently-delete-points-which-are-close-to-other-p

Comment: Are you interested in being able to set the number of points *exactly*, or is a certain error of +/- a small number of points admissible?

Comment: Also related: [(2594)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2594/121), [(11940)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11940/121), [(57938)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57938/121)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Annealing

Found this to be an interesting question and immediately I thought it to be a good application for simulated annealing.

Here's a little unoptimized annealing function I wrote.  The idea is that your points move around like atoms in random directions but they "cool down" over time and move less and settle into a minimum energy configuration state.

My rules are:

1. plan a move in a random direction and random distance of maximum length `step`
2. move only if the distance to the nearest point increases
3. move only if the new location is inside the region

Assumes rm is a globally defined RegionMember function.

```
anneal[pts_, step_] := 
 Module[{np, nn, test1, test2, pl, potentialMoves},
  pl = Length@pts;
  np = Nearest@pts;
  nn = np[#, 2][[2]] & /@ pts;
  potentialMoves = RandomReal[step, pl]*RandomPoint[Circle[], pl];
  test1 = 
   Boole@Thread[
     MapThread[EuclideanDistance[#1, #2] &, {pts, nn}] < 
      MapThread[
       EuclideanDistance[#1, #2] &, {pts + potentialMoves, nn}]];
  test2 = Boole[rm /@ (pts + potentialMoves)];
  pts + potentialMoves*test1*test2]
```

Here is an example with 200 pts, 1000 steps and an anneal rate of .995.  Initial step should be on the order of the region size:

```
Clear[x,y];reg=ImplicitRegion[x^2-y^2<=1,{{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3}}];
rm=RegionMember[reg];
pts=RandomPoint[reg,200];
step=1;
Do[pts=anneal[pts,step=.995*step],1000];
Show[RegionPlot[reg],Graphics[{Black,Point/@pts}]]
```

[image: stippling example]

Here is an animation of the process:

[image]

Comment: It is not a high efficient solution,but it is the answer which I content with indeed.Thanks very much.

Comment: Now that I think about it, one might even consider a hybrid of kirma's and Kelly's approaches: start with annealing for a few steps, and accelerate convergence near the end with Lloyd.

Comment: I think we should make the move have a rough but not a random direction maybe will be better.

Answer (score 22):

Many solutions similar to [how to get $n$ equidistributed points on the unit sphere](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119329/how-to-get-n-equidistributed-points-on-the-unit-sphere/) are possible, especially if one can accept that points are not on the edges of a region. For instance, one can use analytical Lloyd's method:

```
With[{reg = RegularPolygon[5]}, 
 Nest[RegionNearest[reg][
     RegionCentroid@RegionIntersection[reg, #] & /@ 
      MeshPrimitives[VoronoiMesh@#, 2]] &, RandomPoint[reg, 20], 20] //
   Graphics[{LightBlue, reg, Black, Point@#}] &]
```

[image]

This is awfully slow, though.

A much faster variant is to use a Monte Carlo method to estimate Voronoi cell centroids:

```
With[{reg = RegularPolygon[5]}, 
 With[{points = 500, samples = 40000, iterations = 20}, 
   Nest[With[{randoms = Join[#, RandomPoint[reg, samples]]}, 
      RegionNearest[reg][
       Mean@randoms[[#]] & /@ 
        Values@PositionIndex@Nearest[#, randoms]]] &, 
    RandomPoint[reg, points], iterations]] // 
  Graphics[{LightBlue, reg, Black, Point@#}] &]
```

[image]

A more complex concave example (which benefits from higher iteration count) as suggested by @J.M.:

```
With[{reg = 
   Cases[Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonData[
      "HexaSpiral"], _Polygon, \[Infinity]][[1]]}, 
 With[{points = 500, samples = 40000, iterations = 200}, 
   Nest[With[{randoms = Join[#, RandomPoint[reg, samples]]}, 
      RegionNearest[reg][
       Mean@randoms[[#]] & /@ 
        Values@PositionIndex@Nearest[#, randoms]]] &, 
    RandomPoint[reg, points], iterations]] // 
  Graphics[{LightBlue, reg, Black, Point@#}] &]
```

[image]

Comment: Good work,and have you seen this [blog](http://blog.wolfram.com/2016/05/06/computational-stippling-can-machines-do-as-well-as-humans/)?

Comment: This seems to do well with concave regions, too. Try, for instance, ``reg = Cases[Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonData["HexaSpiral"], _Polygon, ∞][[1]]``

Comment: @yode Yes, I've seen it. Lloyd's method is a nice trick people tend to find when thinking of these things. I'm not certain how I found it out, but it's also featured in Mma documentation of `VoronoiMesh`.

Comment: @yode @ kirma Regarding the performance and generalization to arbitrary region, I had [some significant improvements](http://i.stack.imgur.com/66Oz2.png). The key-points are vectorization and compilation. While getting time and appropriate chance, I'd definitely like to share them.

Comment: @Silvia Could I expect that before the deadline of this bounty?

Comment: @yode I'm sincerely sorry to say that I might not be able to find some time until at least 1 month later... Also I think, in principle, my method would have no huge differences from kirma's. It's just the old blog with some numerical optimizations.

Comment: @Silvia Just an ask.Be my guest. :)

Answer (score 10):

This does not give you real control over the number of points, but its one way to get somewhat equally spaced distribution of points:

```
region = ConvexHullMesh[RandomReal[1, {100, 2}]];
<< NDSolve`FEM`
elementMesh = ToElementMesh[region, MeshQualityGoal -> 0];
coordinates = elementMesh[[1]];
triangles = elementMesh[[2, 1, 1]];
centers = 
  Table[
    Sum[{coordinates[[triangles[[i, j]], 1]],coordinates[[triangles[[i, j]], 2]]}, {j, 1, 3}]/3
   , {i, 1, Length[triangles]}];
Show[region, Graphics[Point[centers]]]
```

> [image]

**Update**

Trivial solution, but seems to be relatively quick:

```
numberOfPoints = 500;
region = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Text["K"], _Text];
<< NDSolve`FEM`
elementMesh = ToElementMesh[region, MeshQualityGoal -> 0];
coordinates = Transpose[elementMesh[[1]]];
Xmin = Min[coordinates[[1]]];
Xmax = Max[coordinates[[1]]];
Ymin = Min[coordinates[[2]]];
Ymax = Max[coordinates[[2]]];
scale = (Xmax - Xmin + Ymax - Ymin)/2;
spacing = scale/40;
test[x_] := RegionMember[region, x];
points := DeleteCases[
  Flatten[Table[ If[test[{i, j}], {i, j}, -1], {i, Xmin, Xmax, spacing}, {j, Ymin, Ymax, spacing}], 1] 
  , -1];
(
 data = Table[{1/(spacing = ii scale/300), points // Length} // Reverse, {ii, 10, 20}];
 fun[x_] = NonlinearModelFit[data, a + b x^(1/2), {a, b}, x] // Normal;
 spacing = 1/fun[numberOfPoints];
 (pts = points) // Length
) // AbsoluteTiming
Show[region, Graphics[Point[pts]]]
```

> `{0.187837, 505}`
>
> [image]

We can see that within `0.188` seconds we have generated a distribution of `505` points where we tried to generate a `500` points distribution. The error in number of points is always just a few percent at the most.

Comment: Thanks for the new update. :)And it's seem cannot control the number of points still?

Comment: For given region, you could get desired number of points by fine tuning the `spacing` variable. Requires some trial and error, or you could write a short minimization routine... Would make it slower though.

Comment: @yode Honestly, density of points might be a more objective measure than number of points, since you never know what total area the region has before you generate it. So being able to adjust the spacing is probably more useful than number of points. Don't you agree?

Comment: Actually don't very agree. :)

Comment: @yode see the update of the trivial solution above. This allows to generate a distribution of approximately the desired amount of points. The error is always within a few percent, as far as I have tested.

Comment: How about more complicated region?Such as `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Text["K"], _Text]`

Comment: @yode see new update.

Comment: @yode You can replace the `{ii, 10, 20}` in the definition of `data` by i.e. `{ii, 20, 30}`. This will yield a speedup in calculation but increase the error spread in number of points that are generated.

Answer (score 5):

Since Mma v12.2 spatial point processes have opened yet another possibility with `HardcorePointProcess`, which prevents processes from resulting points being pairwise closer than a specified distance from each other. This is not to such an extent a "packing" as many other answers to this question, since only minimum distance is constrained, but it does demonstrate that there are multiple ways to approach the question. Consider, for instance:

```
With[{reg = 
   Cases[
     Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonData[
      "HexaSpiral"], _Polygon, \[Infinity]][[1]]}, 
 Graphics[{LightBlue, reg, Black,
   Point@RandomPointConfiguration[
      HardcorePointProcess[10000, 2, 2],
      reg, Method -> {"LengthOfRun" -> 10000000}]["Points"]}]]
```

[image]

Here the number of points produced is somewhat random, but depends on the region area, the specified point density (the first argument to `HardcorePointProcess`) and the minimum distance constraint (the second argument).

Answer (score 3):

Rebuilt and little refine for [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/143370/21532)

```
equPoint[region_, pointNum_] := 
 Module[{pts, stepDist, rm, regionRange, beFar, InRegion, moveDir}, 
  pts = RandomPoint[region, pointNum];
  rm = RegionMember[region];
  regionRange = 
   EuclideanDistance @@ Transpose[RegionBounds[region]]/100;
  stepDist = Subdivide[regionRange, 0, 500];
  moveDir = 
   RandomReal[#, pointNum]*RandomPoint[Circle[], pointNum] & /@ 
    stepDist;
  Fold[(beFar = 
      Boole@Thread[
        EuclideanDistance @@@ Nearest[#, #, 2] < 
         EuclideanDistance @@@ Nearest[#1 + #2, #1 + #2, 2]];
     InRegion = Boole[rm /@ (#1 + #2)];
     # + #2*beFar*InRegion) &, N[pts], moveDir]]
```

## Explanation

I have not iterated 1000 times,but make the difference of the last two times less the `pre`,whose default value is `0.001`,after 500 times.And you don't need to consider the size of region.

## Example

```
region = ImplicitRegion[x^2 - y^2 <= 1, {{x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}}];
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[region, 
 Epilog -> {Point[equPoint[region, 200]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is an animation of the process:
[image]