# Test if a list is a constant integer multiple of another list

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-test

I have a list of lists, and I want to eliminate all the lists that are constant integer multiples of another list. My initial approach was to divide the lists using nested tables.

```
ex1 = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 4}, {3, 3, 5}};
Table[Table[
    If[Subtract @@ MinMax[ex1[[j]]/ex1[[i]]] == 0, 
    ex1[[j]] = ex1[[i]]], {j, i + 1, Length[ex1]}], {i, Length[ex1]}];
Union[ex1]
{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {3, 3, 5}}
```

However, some of my lists have zeroes, which breaks my code.

```
ex2 = {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 0}, {2, 2, 4}, {3, 3, 5}};
Table[Table[
    If[Subtract @@ MinMax[ex2[[j]]/ex2[[i]]] == 0, 
    ex2[[j]] = ex2[[i]]], {j, i + 1, Length[ex2]}], {i, Length[ex2]}];
Union[ex2]
"CHAOS ENSUES"
```

I have an alternative approach which is stupid and ugly.

```
ex3 = {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 0}, {2, 2, 4}, {3, 3, 5}};
Table[
    Table[
        Table[
            If[ex3[[i]]*k == ex3[[j]], ex3[[j]] = ex3[[i]]], {k, j}], 
    {j, i + 1, Length[ex3]}], 
{i, Length[ex3]}];
Union[ex3]
{{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 2}, {3, 3, 5}}
```

I'm certain there's a better way, but I can't come up with it. I was frustrated by the ugliness of with my first attempt, but at least it was somewhat clever. Can you suggest something nicer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html) is *much faster* than the pairwise-compare of [`DeleteDuplicates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html) with a custom comparator.

```
jm = DeleteDuplicates[#, Norm[Cross[##]] == 0 &] &;

gb = GatherBy[#, #/Max[1, GCD @@ #] &][[All, 1]] &;

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[{jm, gb}, RandomInteger[9, {#, 3}] &, 5, "IncludeFits" -> True]
```

[image]

Other examples:

- [Checking for duplicates in sublists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30290/121)

Comment: If involves negative multiples, may not get the correct result. `GatherBy[{{1,2,3},{2,4,6},{-2,-4,-6},{1,2,-3},{1,-2,3}},#/Max[1,GCD@@#]&]`

Comment: @expression Caveat noted.  Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

Same principle as kglr's, but using a much cheaper test:

```
DeleteDuplicates[{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 4}, {3, 3, 5}},
                 Norm[Cross[##]] == 0 &]
   {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {3, 3, 5}}
```

---

For eliminating only integer multiples:

```
DeleteDuplicates[{{2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 4}, {3, 3, 5}, {3, 3, 6}, {5, 5, 5}, {8, 8, 8}}, 
                 Norm[Cross[##]] == 0 &&
                 (And @@ Thread[Divisible[##] || Divisible[#2, #1]]) &]
   {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 4}, {3, 3, 5}, {3, 3, 6}, {5, 5, 5}}
```

Answer (score 9):

**Update:**

> *I want to eliminate all the lists that are constant **integer** multiples of another list.*

As noted by Simon in a comment all the methods in my original answer  eliminate rows that are *rational* multiples of another row.

To eliminate a row when it is an *integer* multiple of another row, we can use

```
ClearAll[f]
f = DeleteDuplicates[#, Reduce[# == k #2 || m # == #2, {k, m}, Integers] =!= False &]
```

or

```
f = DeleteDuplicates[#, Resolve[Exists[{k, m}, # == k #2 || m # == #2], Integers] &] &
```

Examples:

```
f @ ex1
```

> {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {3, 3, 5}}

```
ex2 = {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 4}, {3, 3, 5}, {5, 5, 5}};
f @ ex2
```

> {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 5}, {5, 5, 5}}

which is the correct result. The other methods posted so far all  eliminate `{5, 5, 5}` in `ex2` because it is a rational multiple of `{2, 2, 2}`:

```
DeleteDuplicates[ex2, MatrixRank@{##} == 1 &]
```

> {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 5}}

```
jm @ ex2 == gb @ ex2 == DeleteDuplicates[ex2, MatrixRank@{##} == 1 &]
```

> True

**Original answer:**

```
DeleteDuplicates[ex1, MatrixRank @ {##} == 1 &]
DeleteDuplicates[ex1, Length @ SingularValueList @ {##} == 1 &]
DeleteDuplicates[ex1, RowReduce[{##}][[2]] == {0, 0, 0} &]
```

> {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {3, 3, 5}}

Comment: +1 because it's clever but doesn't this eliminate rows which are rational multiples of another row, not just integer multiples?

Comment: @Simon, right... oops. Thank you for the vote.

Comment: @Simon, updated with a clunkier but, I think, correct method.

Answer (score 1):

Just divide one list by the ratio of the first elements of each list. Then check if they’re equal

Comment: should work, but mind the zeros... maybe add some code?

Comment: Good point. This is an easy case to test— simply test if the first element of either list is zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
SeedRandom[1]
mat = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {10^5, 3}];

r1 = GatherBy[mat, #/Max[1, GCD @@ #] &][[All, 1]]; // AbsoluteTiming

r2 = GatherBy[mat, #/Tr@# &][[All, 1]]; // AbsoluteTiming

r1 == r2
```

> {0.548749, Null}
>
> {0.505526, Null}
>
> True

Comment: Wouldn't that code break if you include 0's in your matrix?