# Group a list based on multiples of sublists

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-test, gathering

I have a list of lists like this one, where the sublists vary in length.

```
list = {{0, 1, 2}, {0, -2, 4}, {0, 3, 6}, {1, 2, 3}, {0, 0}, {2, 4, 6}, {-2, -4, -6}, {1, 2, -3}, {1, -2, 3}, {-6, -8, -10}, {0.3, 0.4, 0.5}, {0, 0}};
```

I want to rearrange the list so that each group has all the multiples of the sublists grouped together. The above example should give this reorganized list:

```
{{0, 1, 2}, {0, 3, 6}}
{{0, -2, 4}}
{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 6}, {-2, -4, -6}}
{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
{{1, 2, -3}}
{{1, -2, 3}}
{{-6, -8, -10}, {0.3, 0.4, 0.5}}
```

I have read [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157783/test-if-a-list-is-a-constant-integer-multiple-of-another-list) post, but it’s mainly suitable for positive integer multiples and equal-length sublists. This method fails with my example.

```
GatherBy[list, #/Max[1, GCD @@ #] &]
```

I prefer the solution based on `GatherBy` instead of `Gather`, because `GatherBy` is much more efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated**

```
list = {{0, 1, 2}, {0, -2, 4}, {0, 3, 6}, {1, 2, 3}, {0, 0}, {2, 4, 
    6}, {-2, -4, -6}, {1, 2, -3}, {1, -2, 3}, {-6, -8, -10}, {0.3, 
    0.4, 0.5}, {0, 0}};
f[w_] := Sort@{Normalize[Rationalize@w], -Normalize[Rationalize@w]}
GatherBy[list, f]
```

> `{{{0, 1, 2}, {0, 3, 6}}, {{0, -2, 4}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4,  6}, {-2, -4, -6}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{1, 2, -3}}, {{1, -2,  3}}, {{-6, -8, -10}, {0.3, 0.4, 0.5}}}`

The trick is, for a vector $(x,y,z)$, we map it into **two vectors** $\{ (x,y,z),-(x,y,z) \}$,  and `Sort` the two vectors in this set.

So the two vectors $(a,b,c)$ and $(-a,-b,-c)$ are map into the same order set
$$\{(a,b,c),(-a,-b,-c)\}$$

so they regard as the **same** object!

For example,

```
u = {1, -2, 3};
v = {-1, 2, -3};
Sort[{u, -u}] === Sort[{v, -v}]
(* True *)
```

**Original**

Not so effect.
Here we define a normalize function.

```
Function[w, (Sign@First@w)*Normalize[Rationalize@w, Sqrt[#.#] &]]
```

for example, if  `w={x,y,z}`,we first `Rationalize` `w`,and then calculate
$$ \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$$

after this,we make the $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$ is positive by multiple the vector the sign of x.

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0}, {2, 4, 6}, {-2, -4, -6}, {1, 
    2, -3}, {1, -2, 3}, {-6, -8, -10}, {0.3, 0.4, 0.5}, {0, 0}};
GatherBy[list, 
 Function[w, (Sign@First@w)*Normalize[Rationalize@w, Sqrt[#.#] &]]]
```

> `{{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 6}, {-2, -4, -6}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{1,  2, -3}}, {{1, -2, 3}}, {{-6, -8, -10}, {0.3, 0.4, 0.5}}}`

**Other idea**

Maybe `MatrixRank` is another way.

Comment: Thank you. See my updated,`{{0, 1, 2}, {0, -2, 4}}` should not be grouped together.

Comment: `list = {{0, 1, 2}, {0, -2, 4}, {0, 3, 6}, {1, 2, 3}, {0, 0}, {2, 4, 
    6}, {-2, -4, -6}, {1, 2, -3}, {1, -2, 3}, {-6, -8, -10}, {0.3, 
    0.4, 0.5}, {0, 0}};
Region[#, BaseStyle -> Blue] & /@ (AffineSpace @@ {{#, -#}} & /@ list)`

Comment: `GatherBy[list, 
 Round[Sort@{-#, #} &@{Normalize[#, Norm[#, 1] &]}, .0001] &]`  modified by chy.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[proj]
proj = KroneckerProduct[#, #] &[Normalize @ Rationalize @ #] &;

GatherBy[list, proj] // Column
```

> [image]

```
ClearAll[fit]
fit = Fit[{Table[0, Length@#], #}, Array[x, Length[#]-1], Array[x, Length[#]-1]]&;

GatherBy[list, fit] // Column
```

> [image]

Comment: There seems to be something wrong, consider this example, `GatherBy[{{-11, -11, 22}, {2, -1, -1}, {-6, 10, -4}}, Projection[Table[1, Length@#], #] &]`

Comment: @expression, updated with something that (I hope) works in general.

Comment: Thank you.This should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If we does not insist on using `GatherBy` ,then there other way can be use to get the same result by using `Gather`.

`Gather` is easy to handle.

**Method I**

```
list = {{0, 1, 2}, {0, -2, 4}, {0, 3, 6}, {1, 2, 3}, {0, 0}, {2, 4, 
    6}, {-2, -4, -6}, {1, 2, -3}, {1, -2, 3}, {-6, -8, -10}, {0.3, 
    0.4, 0.5}, {0, 0}, {Sqrt[3], Sqrt[3]}, {1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 
    1}, {2., 2., 2.}, {π Sqrt[3], 2 π Sqrt[3], 
    3 π Sqrt[3]}};
Gather[list, 
 RegionEqual[AffineSpace[{#1, -#1}], AffineSpace[{#2, -#2}]] &]
```

**Method II**

```
list = {{0, 1, 2}, {0, -2, 4}, {0, 3, 6}, {1, 2, 3}, {0, 0}, {2, 4, 
    6}, {-2, -4, -6}, {1, 2, -3}, {1, -2, 3}, {-6, -8, -10}, {0.3, 
    0.4, 0.5}, {0, 0}, {Sqrt[3], Sqrt[3]}, {1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 
    1}, {2., 2., 2.}, {π Sqrt[3], 2 π Sqrt[3], 
    3 π Sqrt[3]}};
Gather[list, 
 Length[#1] == Length[#2] && Norm[#1] == Norm[#2] == 0 || 
   Length[#1] == Length[#2] && Norm[#1]*Norm[#2] != 0 && 
    MatrixRank[{#1, #2}] == 1 &]
```

> `{{{0, 1, 2}, {0, 3, 6}}, {{0, -2, 4}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4,  6}, {-2, -4, -6}, {Sqrt[3] π, 2 Sqrt[3] π,  3 Sqrt[3] π}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{1, 2, -3}}, {{1, -2,  3}}, {{-6, -8, -10}, {0.3, 0.4, 0.5}}, {{Sqrt[3], Sqrt[3]}, {1,  1}}, {{0, 0, 0}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {2., 2., 2.}}}`