# How to pick the maximum of a list? Improving efficiency

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I need to find the element of a list, with the highest weight.

Example:

```
  {{1, 3.80737}, {2, 4.48538}, {3, 2.64947}, {4, 1.06387}, {5, 
  5.07804}, {6, 1.33265}, {7, 9.11426}, {8, 6.90628}, {9, 
  5.34919}, {10, 3.90156}}
```

the program should pick `{7, 9.11426}`.

I've done the following working example:

```
n=50;
tabint = Table[{i, RandomReal[{1, n}]}, {i, 1, n}] (*to generate a random table. This command does not matter for the efficiency of my programme. It's only for this example*)

tabsort = Sort[tabint, (#1[[2]] >= #2[[2]]) &];

initialvls = tabsort[[1]];
```

The thing that bothers me with my code is the sort. It seems that I lose time in sorting the whole list than those I would need to if just looking for the maximum weight. I bet there is a faster way to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S.: I've tried to find other questions similar to this one, but the answers don't seems to be applicable to my problem. May be wrong though...

Comment: @MathLind, thanks for the interest. Unfortunately it does not help. tabint in this example has this shape, but in my programme the first elements are unknown...

Comment: Take a look at `MaxBy` [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19116/12) and `MaximalBy` introduced in version 10.

Comment: @Szabolcs, thanks ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lst = {{1, 3.80737}, {2, 4.48538}, {3, 2.64947}, {4, 1.06387}, {5, 5.07804}, 
       {6, 1.33265}, {7, 9.11426}, {8, 6.90628}, {9, 5.34919}, {10, 3.90156}};

f = #[[Ordering[#[[All, 2]], -1]]][[1]] &;
f@lst
(* {7, 9.11426} *)
```

Timing:

```
n = 500000;
tabint = Table[{i, RandomReal[{1, n}]}, {i, 1, n}];

f@tabint // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.017019,{378308,499999.}} *)

First@Cases[#, {_, Max@#[[All, 2]]}] &@tabint // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.130194,{378308,499999.}} *)
```

Comment: In my computer this is 10x faster than (what to me seems) the canonical way `MaximalBy[tabint, Last] // AbsoluteTiming` - very impressive! (+1)

Answer (score 5):

Without sorting:

```
list = {{1, 3.80737}, {2, 4.48538}, {3, 2.64947}, {4, 1.06387}, {5, 5.07804}, {6, 1.33265}, {7, 9.11426}, {8, 6.90628}, {9, 5.34919}, {10, 3.90156}}

First@Cases[#, {_, Max@#[[All, 2]]}]& @ list
(* {7, 9.11426} *)
```

Comment: +1 Seems pretty nice. I'll just wait for the chance that there are better answers. If not, yours will be accepted ;)

Answer (score 4):

In general, there could be one or more elements with the highest weight so the result would be a list of elements. If you don't care about finding all such cases, your method can be made more efficient by using SortBy. However, the index returned may be different--but the maximun weight will be the same.

```
n = 10000;
SeedRandom[1];
tabint = Table[{i, 
    Round[RandomReal[{1, RandomReal[{2, 3}]}], .005]}, {i, 1, n}];

Sort[tabint, (#1[[2]] >= #2[[2]]) &][[1]] // Timing
```

> {0.184576, {506, 2.98}}

```
SortBy[tabint, Last][[-1]] // Timing
```

> {0.005880, {9033, 2.98}}

```
(max = Max[tabint[[All, 2]]]; 
  Select[tabint, #[[2]] == max &]) // Timing
```

> {0.010959, {{506, 2.98}, {9033, 2.98}}}

```
(max = Max[tabint[[All, 2]]]; 
  Cases[tabint, _?(#[[2]] == max &)]) // Timing
```

> {0.012999, {{506, 2.98}, {9033, 2.98}}}

Comment: Why does `SortBy[tabint, Last][[-1]]` beat `Sort[tabint, (#1[[2]] >= #2[[2]]) &][[1]]` so much? After all, they all need to do sorting.

Comment: @hengxin - Don't know, someone from WRI would have to answer.