# Dropping disordered numbers in a list

Tags: filtering, sorting, order

I have a list of numbers like
`l1 = (1,2,3,4,8)` and clearly, `l1` is in order (next number is greater than previous number).

Well, I have a list of `l2 = {1,2,4,3,8}`. Because `3` is not in order, I want to drop `3` so that I have a new list of `l2new = {1,2,4,8}` which is now in order.

What is the algorithm to have `l2new` from `l2`?

To clarify my purpose, I introduce another example:
If I have `l3 = {1,2,8,4,5}`, then I want to have `l3new = {1,2,8}`.

Comment: Related: [Arrange a list in ascending order by deleting list elements](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/203502/106) where `DeleteDuplicates[{1,2,5,3,4,6}, GreaterEqual]` is given (in a comment) by @Roman

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
IncreasingSubset[list_] := 
  Fold[If[#2 >= Last[#1], Append[#1, #2], #1] &, {First@list}, Rest@list]
```

Try it:

```
IncreasingSubset[l3]
(* {1, 2, 8} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9):

Another way is as follows:

```
ddlist[lst_] := Tally[lst, #2 <= #1 &][[All, 1]]
```

Test:

```
l2 = {1, 2, 4, 3, 8};
l3 = {1, 2, 8, 4, 5};
l4 = {1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 6};
ddlist[l2]
(*{1, 2, 4, 8}*)
ddlist[l3]
(*{1, 2, 8}*)
ddlist[l4]
(*{1, 2, 5, 6}*)
```

Comment: Neat and surprising

Answer (score 5):

One way, probably not the most efficient:

```
ddb[alist_] := 
 FoldPair[{If[#1[[-1]] <= #2, Join[#1, {#2}], #1], 
    If[#1[[-1]] <= #2, Join[#1, {#2}], #1]} &, alist[[1 ;; 1]], 
  alist[[2 ;;]]]
```

Checks:

```
ddb[{1, 2, 3, 4, 8}]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 8} *)
ddb[{1, 2, 4, 3, 8}]
(* {1, 2, 4, 8} *)
ddb[{1, 2, 8, 4, 5}]
(* {1, 2, 8} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps:

```
f[u_] := u //. {a___, b_, c_, d___} /; b > c :> {a, b, d}
```

For, example:

```
Column[# -> f@# & /@ {{1, 2, 4, 3, 8}, {1, 2, 8, 4, 5, 12}, {1, 2, 8, 
    4, 5, 6, 12}, {2, 1}, {2, 1, 3, 4}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

First a test case:

All troughs need to be removed from the sublists. The following will provide a visual feedback.

```
FixedPointList[
 First /@ Split[#, Greater] &, {1, 2, 4, 3, 8, 6, 10, 11, 7, 10}]
ListLinePlot /@ %
```

[image]

---

**Using `FixedPoint`:**

```
lists = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 8}, {1, 2, 4, 3, 8}, {1, 2, 8, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 5, 
    3, 4, 6}, {2, 1}, {2, 1, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 4, 8, 5, 12}, {1, 2, 4, 3, 
    8, 6, 10, 11, 7, 10}};

{# -> FixedPoint[First /@ Split[#, Greater] &, #] & /@ lists } // 
 Map[Column]
```

[image]

Comment: `lists` has elements that have been borrowed from other answers on the page with thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A late and simple answer:

```
list = {1, 2, 4, 3, 8};

Union @ FoldList[Max] @ list
```

{1, 2, 4, 8}

Example data from earlier answers:

```
lists = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 8}, {1, 2, 4, 3, 8}, {1, 2, 8, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 5, 
    3, 4, 6}, {2, 1}, {2, 1, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 4, 8, 5, 12}, {1, 2, 4, 3, 
    8, 6, 10, 11, 7, 10}}; 

# -> Union @ FoldList[Max, #] & /@ lists // Column
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can say:

```
l2new = Split[l2, Greater][[All,1]]
```

Comment: I like trying to use `Split`, but this doesn't work. Test it with `l3`.

Comment: try  replacing  `Split` with `Gather`?